# Mdadm Raid5 kicking non-fresh drive from array

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I set up a mdadm raid5 with 3 drives initially: sdc1, sdd1, sde1. They array creation was successful without issues. Later I decided to extend the array using one more drive. After proper partitioning, I added the device sdf1 to the array and expanded the partition all without issues. I had the drives in an jbod, but I needed to update to a newer jbod to have more available bays. Before I moved the physical drives to he new jbod, I unmounted the array (/dev/md0) and proceeded to remove each device one by one, but I forgot to stop the mdadm process `mdadm --stop`.

Now when I spin up all the drives in the new jbod (same server computer), and try to assemble the array, only 3 of them are assembled, except for the last one `/dev/sdf1`. Neither drive has any error , and the metadata of them all seems to indicate that they are part of the same array. However, the device `/dev/sdf1` is being shown as `removed` in the mdadm array and that is the only one that shows the wrong array state `.AAA` instead of `AA.A` like the other 3 drives.

Is it still possible to get mdadm to recognize this drive as part of the array? So far, my attempts have failed and I keep getting an error message in the logs stating that `/dev/sdf1` is a non-fresh drive and is being kicked from the array.

Comment: [Never use RAID5 with HDDs](https://www.askdbmgt.com/why-raid5-should-be-avoided-at-all-costs.html).